# Ghost(node.js) app - 503 err after git push in OpenShift hosting

Tags: node.js, openshift, ghost

1. I created ghost blog in OpenShift host. Everything worked fine.
2. I wanted to make some changes in css file(change the margin of the page title), so i did git pull the resources, made changes in css file locally, and git push back with command git push -f(force) openshift master, because without -f, I couldn't do this push.
3. After this "git push" command, my app got broke, and now, the http outputs 503 error...

I tried to restart my app, but it doesn't help. Don't know why it crashed.

Comment: Have you checked your log files?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what actually happened with your new change.Check the app logs.

First ssh to your app

```
ssh 1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef@your-app-domain.rhcloud.com
```

and then cd to logs directory

```
cd app-root/logs
```

tail the contents of nodejs.log file

This may not actually resolve your issue but logs can help you.